# Dynamic drop down menu will not create based on selection

Tags: javascript

So i'm working on a project that creates three drop down menus that appear based on the option selected on the first.  When I select from the first menu, "Male" or "Female" the correct menus appear( example, when Male is selected, the drop down with the options ""Human", "Dwarf", "Orc" appear). However, after that I can not get a third drop down menu to appear based on the next selection using the same methods before.  At this point I am very lost.

```
var step1 = ["Choose Gender?", "Male", "Female"];
var step2 = [["Choose your race!", "Human", "Dwarf", "Orc"],["Choose your race!", "Fairy", "Elf", "Centaur"]];
var step3 = [["Human Class!", "Warrior", "Sorcerer", "Theif"], ["Elf Class!", "Cleric", "Necromancer", "Priest"], ["Dwarf Class!", "Cannonner", "Rifelman", "Engineer"], ["Orc Class!", "Beserker","Warlock", "Shaman"], ["Fairy Class!", "Druid", "Arcanist", "Mystic"]];
function testData(){
    menuCreate(step3[0]);
}
function init() {
    menuCreate(step1);

    var dropdown = document.getElementById("form");
    dropdown.onchange = function(event){    
        if (dropdown.value == "Male"){
            //menuCreate(step2[0]);

                var myDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");

                var next = document.createElement('input');
                next.setAttribute('type','button');
                next.setAttribute('value','Next');
                next.setAttribute('onclick','maleRace()');
                myDiv.appendChild(next);
        } else if (dropdown.value == "Female"){
            //menuCreate(step2[1]);

                myDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");

                femaleNext = document.createElement('input');
                femaleNext.setAttribute('type','button');
                femaleNext.setAttribute('value','Next');
                femaleNext.setAttribute('onclick','femaleRace()');
                myDiv.appendChild(femaleNext);
        } 

     } 

} // end init()
function menuCreate(step1){
    //console.log(step1);
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    var titleElement = document.createElement("h1");

    titleElement.setAttribute('style','color:white');
    titleElement.setAttribute('id','guide');

    var selectForm = document.createElement('select');

    selectForm.id = "form";
    myDiv.appendChild(selectForm);

    for (var i=0; i< step1.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = step1[i];
        option.text = step1[i];
        selectForm.appendChild(option);

    }






} // end menuCreate()

function maleRace(){
    menuCreate(step2[0]);

    var down = document.getElementById("form");
        down.onchange = function(event){
        if (down.value == "Human"){
                menuCreate(step3[0]);
                var div = document.createElement("div");

                var next = document.createElement('input');
                next.setAttribute('type','button');
                next.setAttribute('value','Next');
                next.setAttribute('onclick','maleRace()');
                div.appendChild(next);
        }

    }
} // end maleRace()
```

Please note I cant use JQUERY or innerHTML/innerText.  I have to do this using normal JavaScript the problem is that when I select "Human" on the second menu, I am supposed to get another menu that uses step3[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `menuCreate` function, you're setting an `id` attribute to the `select` element: `selectForm.id = "form";`. After you call it for the second time (for the second step), you have two elements with the same id in your document. Then, when you try to add the `onchange` event handler on the `maleRace` function - `document.getElementById("form"); down.onchange = function(event){` you actually attach this handler to the first `select` element (the gender one) instead of the second one.

A nice way to solve this problem, will be to add a second argument to the `menuCreate` function like so: `function menuCreate(step1, id){`. Then, change this line a bit from `selectForm.id = "form";` to `selectForm.id = id;`.

Then, change every call to the `createMenu` function to have its own id:

```
function init() {
    menuCreate(step1, 'step1form');
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("step1form");


function maleRace(){
    menuCreate(step2[0], 'step2form');
    var down = document.getElementById("step2form");
```

You can check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXJwBv?editors=1011

Comment: That worked! thank you, you saved me from a restless night!